# VBA Expected An "="

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a simple `For` loop in VBA, as per the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

However, I get an error on this line:

```
For iiii As Integer = 1 To 20
```

It says I have a syntax error on this line, but I don't understand why when I am writing it just like the example.

The entire loop is like so:

```
For iiii As Integer = 1 To 20
worksheet.Range("B1:B20").Value = "=getSalesData(A" & iiii & ")"
Next iiii
```

Comment: That's VB.Net syntax.  In VBA you cannot declare variables in-line.  so you'll have to do `Declare iiii As Integer` first and then do the `For iii = 1 to 20`.

Comment: VBA is a quite different, and much older, language than VB (aka VB.NET). The acronym VB was once-upon-a-time used to identify what is now termed either VB6 or Classic VB, but Microsoft retasked that acronym in 2003.

Comment: You should likely use `worksheet.Range("B1:B20").FORMULA = "=getSalesData(A" & iiii & ")"` . If the receiving cell is formatted as Text, you could end up with a text string that looks like your formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. First off, the For Each...Next statement is malformed as VB.Net style, not VBA. Second, you are iterating through the loop 20 times but putting the formula in all of B1:B20 each time. You could put the formula into one cell each time.

```
Dim iiii As long
For iiii  = 1 To 20
    worksheet.Range("B" & iiii).Formula = "=getSalesData(A" & iiii & ")"
Next iiii
```

Note that I have used the [Range .Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) and not the [Range .Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) to assign the formula. If you explicitly tell Excel that you are providing a formula then that is what you get. If the cell was formatted as text and you did not specify the Range .Formula property you would get a cell that had `=getSalesData(A1)` as a text string. Be specific whenever you can or suffer the consequences of letting Excel make the decisions for you.

Finally, the loop is actually unnecessary. You can bulk load the formula without the loop.

```
worksheet.Range("B1:B20).Formula = "=getSalesData(A1)"
```

That will change the formula to *=getSalesData(A1), =getSalesData(A2), =getSalesData(A3), etc* as it is filled into B1:B20.

Answer (score 4):

VBA isn't VB.Net

In VB.Net you can blend variable declarations and control structures in a way that seems very natural if you are coming from C++ or Java. In VBA you can't. You need

```
Dim iiii As integer 'typically at top of sub or function

For iiii  = 1 To 20
    worksheet.Range("B1:B20").Value = "=getSalesData(A" & iiii & ")"
Next iiii
```

Comment: Is there a reason when I do this that the values start at 20 rather than 1?

For example, cell `B1` is `=getSalesData(A20)` instead of `A1`

Comment: Is the loop necessary at all? Stuffing a formula with relative cell references into B1:B20 once should be enough.

Comment: @Jeeped -- good catch. Still, the OP needs to be aware of the VBA vs. VB.Net syntax for when they really do need a loop.